# How should I restart a service using ansible?

Tags: ansible

I tried to use Ansible service module to restart a service but I got an error.

```
 tasks:
    - ini_file: dest=/etc/dd-agent/datadog.conf
               section=Main
               option=use_mount
               state=absent
      register: ddagent
    - service: name='datadog-agent' state=reloaded
      when: ddagent.changed
```

This generated this error: `ERROR: change handler (restart datadog) is not defined`

I know that an alternative is to execute:

```
- command: "service datadog-agent restart"
```

Still, in this case what's the purpose of the service module?

Comment: What happens if you use `state=restarted` instead?

Comment: What is your ansible version?

Comment: Checking datadog's docs they only seem to support restart instead of reload and that seems to line up with the error message you are getting

Comment: I know this is a pretty hard necro, but it would be cool to accept the answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 11):

You should add the following code:

```
handlers:
  - name: restart datadog
    service: name=datadog-agent state=restarted
```

The problem that you are facing is that you don't have the handler defined. This will do the job